# How to present ViewController when tab is selected on UITabBarController?

Tags: ios

I have a UITabBarController with a profile tab. I want to present a login view controller if the profile tab is pressed, but the user is not logged in. If the user presses cancel, I want the tab bar controller to have the same tab selected as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use UITabBarControllerDelegate

```
-tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
```

or

```
-tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

Detect your profile controller and present login controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate